# It is possible to include a process counter in jquery and ajax displayed in a div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a for loop in jQuery within which an AJAX is called. The AJAX in turn generates a query in PHP, after bringing the result that I would like to put a counter in a div each time this process is carried out in such a way that the user can see the changes. Currently when this happens it is locked to the sun until it ends.
..............

Please forgive my delay

```js
var NumsFacts = 10;
var i = 0;
do{
    $.ajax({
          url: 'myfile.php',  
          global: false,
          type: "POST",
          data : ({ 
            op      : "Hab",
            numberof: i
            }),
        dataType  : "JSON",
        async   : false,
        success : function(data) {  
                 $("#DivMessage").html("Send..." + i + " Number: " + numberof + "<br/>");       
            }
    });
    i++;
    }while(i < NumsFacts);
```

Comment: Can't you increment that counter in your success Ajax function?

Comment: My understanding is that you do not have setInterval() in there. Excuse me please if you have

Comment: Hey @Camilo - Do you mind sharing some code that you've written so far. It will help us understand our problem better.